Load the side menu items by condition
I have a widget that serves to display a website (widget). And several options for the side menu (widget B).
Is it possible to load widget B immediately after loading widget A? This is necessary to get information from the site, according to which widget B will be selected.
Widget A:
class MainPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MainPage({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: SecondColor,
      ),
      body: Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: InteractiveViewer(
          panEnabled: false, // Set it to false to prevent panning.
          boundaryMargin: EdgeInsets.all(80),
          maxScale: 2.5,
          child: WebViewWidget(
            controller: controller,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      drawer: MainMenu(),
    );
  }
}

Choosing Widget B:
Widget condition() {
  getRole();///Getting information from the site
  Widget widget;
  switch (UserRole) {
    case "ROLE_DISPATCHER":
      widget = DispatherMenu();
      break;
    case "ROLE_EXECUTOR":
      widget = ExecutorMenu();
      break;
    case "ROLE_CUSTOMER":
      widget = CustomerMenu();
      break;
    default:
      widget = DefaultMenu();
  }
  return widget;
}

class MainMenu  extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Drawer(
      child: condition(),
    );

  }
}

One of the options for widget B:
class DefaultMenu extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                gradient: LinearGradient(
                    begin: FractionalOffset.topLeft,
                    end: FractionalOffset.bottomRight,
                    colors: [
                      PrimaryColor,
                      SecondColor,
                    ],
                    tileMode: TileMode.clamp)
            ),
            accountName: Text('GrainLogist'),
            accountEmail: Text('Управление логистикой'),
            currentAccountPicture: CircleAvatar(
              backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/images/Logo1.png'),
              backgroundColor: Color(0xAA2b677a),
            ),
          ),
          ListTile(
        title: Text('Контакты'),
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
          ),
        ]
    );
  }
}

I tried to call widgets at the same time, but widget A did not have time to load completely.
